# Having more UseState in a functional react typescript component is good?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and Typescript. I have a functional typescript component like below,

```
const myComponent = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  
const[state1,setState1]= useState<string[]>();
.
.
.
.
so on
return(
  );
}
```

So I have more number of usestate. In above I given only one for example. But in actual code I have more than 20. So I want to know that having more number of states in a single functional component is good? Or is there any other way to make my states look good. ***I want to make sure  that I'm meeting the good coding standard.*** Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

React will patch change state event so it will not effect to much when you use multiple `useState` on your code. But you can create a custom hook to make your code more clean and readable

Comment: if you provide an example for it , then I will be more clear about it

Answer (score 1):

It is better to keep all your component state in a one hook, like this

```js
let [state, setState] = useState({field1: "", field2: ""});
```

You can read more here, [thinking in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple `useState` that logically belong together you can use [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one. useReducer also lets you optimize performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.

Run the snippet to see how it works.

```js
const { useReducer, useEffect } = React;

const colorReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
      case 'changeColor':
        const r = (state.r + action.payload) % 255;
        const g = (state.g + action.payload) % 255;
        const b = (state.b + action.payload) % 255;
        return {
           r,g,b
        }
  }
  return state;
};

const ColorChanger = () => {
  const [color, dispatch] = useReducer(colorReducer, {r: 100, g: 150, b: 125});
  
  function changeRandomColor(){
     dispatch({type: "changeColor", payload: getRandomInt(255)});
  }
  
  const style = { 
     width: "120px", height: "120px",
     background: rgbToHex(color)
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={changeRandomColor} style={style} >
       <pre>{JSON.stringify(color, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<div><p>Click the square below to change the color</p><ColorChanger /></div>, document.getElementById("root"));


function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}


function rgbToHex(rgb) {
  function toHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
  }

  const redHex = toHex(rgb.r);
  const greenHex = toHex(rgb.g);
  const blueHex = toHex(rgb.b);

  return `#${redHex}${greenHex}${blueHex}`;
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can also take a look at my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/rene-link/pen/KKqPQBw).